Clustering and samples weighting (using GEE)
I am currently analyzing the social factors associated with the prevalence of infectious diseases in European countries using GEE models. My data is based on patients covered by a specific health insurance, which raises concerns about external validity. Specifically, the prevalence might be biased due to different ethnic groups being overrepresented in the insured population.
Should I adjust for the proportion of each ethnic group (from the whole country's population) in my model, use these proportions as a weighting factor, or consider clustering by ethnic group to address the potential bias? What would be the best approach to ensure my results are more generalizable to the overall population?
Thank you!
